# Is jQuery compulsory when using bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I have mainly been using the jQuery library and have just started using AngularJS.

I have read a few tutorials on how to use Angular, but I am not clear on why or when to use it, or what benefits I may find in comparison to just using jQuery.

It seems to me that Angular makes you think MVC, which perhaps means that you view your webpage as a template + data combination. You use {{data bindings}} whenever you feel you would have dynamic data. Angular will then provide you a $scope handler, which you can populate statically or through calls to the web server. This appears characteristically similar to JSP way of designing webpages. Do I need Angular for this?

For simple DOM manipulation, which does not involve data manipulation (eg: color changes on mousehover, hiding/showing elements on click), jQuery or vanilla JS is sufficient and cleaner. This assumes that the model in Angular's MVC is anything that reflects data on the page, and hence, CSS properties like color, display/hide, etc changes don't affect the model. Does Angular have any advantages over jQuery or vanilla JS for DOM manipulations?

What can Angular do that makes it useful for development in comparison to what jQuery can do along with plugins?

Answer (score 0):

How does Angular makes things easier than just simple jQuery? Consider the following simple examples:

```
<div>
    <h1 id="header">Hi!</h1>
    <form>
        <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="firstName" />
        <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="lastName" />
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        function UpdateName() {
            var firstName = $('#firstName').val();
            var lastName = $('#lastName').val();
            $('#header').text('Hi, ' + firstName + ' ' + lastName + '!');
        }

        $('#firstName').change(function () {
            UpdateName();
        });
        $('#lastName').change(function () {
            UpdateName();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Above would be how you update the header with the input name in jQuery. In this simple example, the handler for the first name update and the last name update is the same, so you can re-use that code. However, if you were to update more places, the handler would be full of DOM manipulation code.

```
<div ng-controller="TheController">
    <h1>Hi, {{First Name}} {{Last Name}}!</h1>
    <form>
        <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="firstName" ng-model="firstName" />
        <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="lastName" ng-model="lastName" />
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    myApp.controller('TheController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.firstName = '';
        $scope.lastName = '';
    }]);
</script>
```

Above is how you the same thing in Angular. Notice how there is no DOM manipulation code? All that is handled by Angular, letting you deal with the actual business logic in your controller.

Of course, you can do all the things you need to do with vanilla JavaScript. What Angular buys you is separation of different logics. What if you need to update 10 different places in the DOM and send a POST request to your API on an input field update? The `onchange` handler for the field in jQuery would be very messy and complicating, whereas in Angular, you should be able to do that with ease.